# index matrix with array

Tags: matlab, indexing

I'd like to index matrix

```
x=[1:5;6:10]
```

x =

```
1    2    3    4    5
6    7    8    9   10
```

using array

```
 [1,2,1,2,1]
```

to get

```
1 7 3 9 5
```

I tried this:

```
x([1,2,1,2,1],:)

ans =

    1    2    3    4    5
    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5
    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5
```

but that is not what I want. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) with [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
>> v = x(sub2ind(size(x),a,1:5))
v =
     1     7     3     9     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Let

```
ind = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1];
offset = [1:size(x, 1):numel(x)] - 1;
```

then

```
x(ind + offset)
```

returns what you want. This assumes that your index vector has an entry for every column of `x` and uses linear indexing to add a column offset to every in-column index.